# Cython - trying to modify function in subclass which is already declared in superclass , but error occurs

Tags: python, class, inheritance, cython

I coded these four classes in jupyter-notebook. first two classes are in python and the other two classes with similar operations are in cython:

```
%load_ext cython

%%cython

# py_child inherits from py_parent
class py_parent:
    def __init__(self, var1, var2):
        self.var1 = var1
        self.var2 = var2

    def func1(self):
        return self.var1 + self.var2

    def func2(self):
        return self.var1 * self.var2

    class py_child(py_parent):
        def func1(self, inp):
            return self.var1 + self.var2, self.var1 + inp, self.var2 + inp

# In the next cell I coded these modules
# cy_child inherits from cy_parent

cdef class cy_parent:
    cdef public:
        int var1, var2
    def __init__(self, var1, var2):
        self.var1 = var1
        self.var2 = var2

    cpdef int func1(self):
        return self.var1 + self.var2

    cpdef int func2(self):
        return self.var1 * self.var2

cdef class cy_child(cy_parent):
    def __init__(self, var1, var2):
        super().__init__(var1, var2)

    cpdef tuple func1(self, int inp):
        return self.var1 + self.var2, self.var1 + inp, self.var2 + inp
```

I run code below for python classes and it works just fine:

```
a = py_child(1,1)
print(a.func1(2))
```

But for cy_child and cy_parent I get this error:

```
cpdef tuple func1(self, int inp):
     ^
------------------------------------------------------------
```

`Signature not compatible with previous declaration`

I also get this error after that:
`Call with wrong number of arguments (expected 1, got 2)`

Why this error happens for cython classes but not python classes.
Assume that I want the superclass `cy_parent` keep the `func1` function unchanged and want to modify its subclass `cy_child.func1` function in the way I showed. How can I fix the error then?
Any suggestion would be highly appreciated.

Comment: in C the return type needs to stay consistent, so if `func1` returns an `int` in then the subclass also needs to return an `int`.

Comment: I see. so there is no way to rewrite the function just like the pure python one and I have to modify the superclass func. Am I right?

Comment: I could possibly give other suggestions if you give me a less abstract example.  But no, if the parent class has a method that returns one type the override needs to return the same type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will "work" if you change `cpdef` to `def`, but what you're doing makes no sense.

Inheritance usually indicates a *"is a"* relationship - i.e. `cy_child` is a `cy_parent` and should be able to do everything a `cy_parent` can do, (and possibly some other stuff). Therefore, it can be used in your code anywhere that you can use a `cy_parent`. By trying to change the function signature you're making it so that it can do longer do the same things and so breaking that rule.

With a `cpdef` function your asking Cython to generate code so that the following code generates a fast C function call to the correct function whether it's passed a `cy_parent` or `cy_child`:

```
def example(cy_parent x):
  x.func1()
```

Since the functions take different numbers of arguments it is not possible to do this and hence Cython (rightly) complains. With pure Python code you put the problem off until you run the code, but the problem still exists (you'll get an exception about the wrong number of arguments).

There's two "solutions":

1. you shouldn't be using inheritance since it doesn't represent the model you're trying to code.
2. If you're just trying to add extra functionality onto `cy_child` then you should give the new function a different name (since it's doing something different). This represents a case where you still want to be able to use `cy_parent`'s `func1` with `cy_child` but you also want the option of doing a similar action with an extra argument.

Comment: That's right. All I want is extra functionality to my subclass function. The abstract code I used in this question is too simple and the real code is a little complicated, But I really have to say you told me what I just needed.

Comment: My questions mostly are practical cases, But nobody upvotes them. Is there anything I can do to get more votes for my questions or answers (I ask it to add more quality for next times)?

Comment: I don't think the Cython tag has much traffic so nothing ever gets too many votes quickly. I would worry too much unless things are regularly downvoted. I think the issue with this question is that "Signature not compatible with previous declaration" is reasonably clear what's wrong and the simple solution is not to do it. You possibly should make clear what problem is solved by changing the signature since that's what the real question is (while still trying to keep it simple, which is hard...)